# Video player for online video streaming (not Http live streaming) for android?

Tags: android, video-streaming, h.264, mpeg-4

I am currently using android media player and switching different bandwidth URLs manually named on button click but video streaming is not smooth. App minimum sdk version is 15. I already looked up for Exoplayer but it is very large library. My expectation is for  smooth streaming player which should be small in size and customizable also.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for too late answer but there is no other customizable video player available which is able to stream video based upon network bandwidth (except than ExoPlayer Android-best one )  but the only issue is that it supports from min Api level 16 My need was min SDK 15. So i customized standard media player for Api level 15 and using ExoPlayer for further Api level.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many libraries available some of them are listed below.
you can clone repository and customize as per your requirement.

https://github.com/afollestad/easy-video-player

https://github.com/lipangit/jiecaovideoplayer

Comment: thanks for response what if i want to change video quality  smoothly  according to network bandwidth like youtube.

Comment: How to start auto play using this libarry?